# Trouble passing results from DataReader to textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am making an admin section that will allow access to several small SQL tables in my project.

I have repeaters set up to show my lists with a button to bring up a Modal for adding a new entry or editing an existing one. The code behind stores a value from the selected row, and then I would like to query my SQL Class to return a value to fill my text boxes. The code works back to the SQL Class and I can display a message box and get the proper results. I can't however get it to pass the value if the query back to the VB page to fill the text boxes.

Here is the Repeater

```
    <%--Employee Repeater--%>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="display" id ="employeeList">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Email
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Update
                    </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("name")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("email")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdEditName" runat="server" Text="Edit/Delete" CommandArgument= '<%#Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>' OnClick="EditName"/> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

My Code Behind

```
   'Open Name Modal bound to repeater
    Public Sub EditName(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim wLink As New Button
        Edit = True
        wLink = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        txtEditId.Text = wLink.CommandArgument

        SQL.RunReader("SELECT name from Admin_Contacts WHERE Admin_Contacts.id = '" & txtEditId.Text & "' ")
        txtEditName.Text = results

        SQL.RunReader("SELECT email from Admin_Contacts WHERE Admin_Contacts.id = '" & txtEditId.Text & "' ")
        txtEditEmail.Text = results

        ModalName.Show()

    End Sub
```

And the code in my SQL Class

```
Public Function RunReader(ByVal Query As String) As String
    Dim results As String = ""
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
        Dim R As SqlDataReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
        While R.Read
            results = (R(0))
            'MsgBox is just to show that I am getting results
            MsgBox(results)
        End While
        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQLCon.Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim results = SQL.RunReader("SELECT name from Admin_Contacts WHERE Admin_Contacts.id = '" & txtEditId.Text & "' ")
        txtEditName.Text = results
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete the runreader function with return statement

```
Public Function RunReader(ByVal Query As String) As String
Dim results As String = ""
Try
    SQLCon.Open()
    SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
    Dim R As SqlDataReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
    While R.Read
        results = (R(0))
        'MsgBox is just to show that I am getting results
        MsgBox(results)
    End While
    SQLCon.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        SQLCon.Close()
    End If
End Try
Return results
End Function
```

Then call this method as

```
Dim results =  SQL.RunReader("SELECT name from Admin_Contacts WHERE Admin_Contacts.id = '" & txtEditId.Text & "' ")
```